# How to stop asp validation on an optional telerik masked text field?

Tags: asp.net, validation, telerik, radmaskedtextbox

My setup:

In my ASP.NET project I have a RadAjaxPanel, within that panel is a RadMaskedTextBox and ASP RegexValidator tied to a RadButton for submission.

The relevant code follows:

```
    <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox runat="server" ID="radTxtSSN" RenderMode="Lightweight" Mask="###-##-####"></telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="radTxtSSN" ErrorMessage="Invalid SSN format" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

On the first submit or action that causes a postback-translated-to-ajax event to occur, everything works fine.  In other words, the field submits, the radTxtSSN validates empty, and I can ignore the empty SSN field.  I can even focus the box then leave it empty, or fill it in and delete it without causing problems on the FIRST submit only.

When this finishes, however, all actions would could cause a update or postback or ajax call get stalled behind the Regex validation failing on the SSN field.
The error message even shows up saying "Invalid SSN format" even though it's empty.

[The only thing I've found on this topic so far.](http://www.telerik.com/forums/masked-text-box-triggers-regular-expression-validator-when-empty)
Telerik support staff claims this has been fixed, and to a degree they are correct but they ignored edge and corner cases when they fixed it.

What can fix this?  I don't have any good reasons to adding a lot of behind-code or custom-validator logic as this is the only area this is used or an issue.

Comment: What is you current version of telerik  'UI for ASP.NET AJAX '

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior on my side. 
If you can make a sample runnable that show the weird behavior.
You will win some Telerik point . Its not a big $$/hours. But really Cool to show Telerik Support team you re not crazy.

Comment: If the bug is real. go to serverside validation. Or do your custom js to validate this one.

Comment: @PierreLebon Current version I have installed looks like it is v2016.1.113.45  so I'm after the release that says it was fixed, but definitely not at the most current one.

If my old version isn't the problem I'll build a sample to try and reproduce it.